# Can't match pattern with regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a strange issue with regex.. I want to filter out the "quoted" text part consisting of CAPITAL LETTERS. It seems to work fine in regex tester [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) but it doesn't work in my Perl code. The text I have to filter out from looks like this:

```
<option value="NASDAQ">NASDAQ Stock Exchange</option>
<option value="NYMEX">New York Merchantile Exchange</option>
<option selected="selected" value="NYSE">New York Stock Exchange</option>
<option value="NZX">New Zealand Exchange</option>
```

And I use the following regexp:

```
$line =~ m/"([A-Z]*)"/
```

Which I expect to match: NASDAQ, NYMEX, NYSE and NZX. However in practice, NYSE is not filtered out for some reason...

Can anyone help me with this issue?

---

**Update:**
Unfortunately, the above issue is my fault. I didn't notice that I had an additional filter, earlier in my code, which was filtering out only strings which include "option value" pattern. So since the "NYSE" string contains "option selected" pattern - it was discarded. I changed the code to filter by "option" and it works as expected now.

Comment: It seems ok, can you give more information? Paste more code, for instance?

Comment: Do you want to match empty strings? If not, try: $line =~ m/"([A-Z]+)"/g;  or to work in any language: $line =~ m/"([[:upper:]]+)"/;

Comment: Voting to close because code which was not included was the only cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression provided works as expected, it will match:

1. a substring starting with `"`
2. continues with uppercase characters zero or more times
3. ends with a `"`

There is something else what's wrong with your code if `NYSE` isn't match. I assume you split your input on every line and then execute the mentioned regular expression.

The below should then be equivalent:

```
my $haystack =<<EOT;
<option value="NASDAQ">NASDAQ Stock Exchange</option>
<option value="NYMEX">New York Merchantile Exchange</option>
<option selected="selected" value="NYSE">New York Stock Exchange</option>
<option value="NZX">New Zealand Exchange</option>
EOT


for my $line (split "\n", $haystack) {
  print $line =~ m/"([A-Z]*)"/;
  print "\n";
}
```

output

```
NASDAQ
NYMEX
NYSE
NZX
```

---

#### An educated guess..

Without the regular expression flag `/g` the match operator will only return **the first** match. So if your line contains more than one substring matching the expression only the first located will be returned.

See the below example:

```
my $haystack = "hello WORLD and STACKOVERFLOW";

print join (':', $haystack =~ m/([A-Z]+)/ ), "\n";
print join (':', $haystack =~ m/([A-Z]+)/g), "\n";
```

output

```
WORLD
WORLD:STACKOVERFLOW
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want just the values, not the selected.  This would eliminate the NYSE entry.

```
$line =~ m/value="([A-Z]*)"/
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected for my perl version (5.8.9). Maybe you match for value="" as Bill said, or do a m/.../g to scan the whole line.